# Forward request from IIS based on custom logic

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, routes, arr

I want to forward rest service request coming to Server A to Server B and C.

The condition to forward depends upon data coming. The condition is pretty complex and I would  have to make a DB call to know where the request should go.

Does anyone know hows to achieve this in IIS.

I am not able to change client code at all.

Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 0):

I don't think IIS can do this all alone but WCF Routing (introduced in 4.0) should be able to do it.

You can have a router service which will route the request as per routing table.

The routing table routes the request on the basis of parameters (filterdata)

Introduction to routing
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517422.aspx

Something similar to your requirement
http://blogs.profitbase.com/tsenn/?p=23

Thanks,

A